# PowerShell and exif data in Json format

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-4.0, exiftool

I'm currently trying to learn powershell. I have some code that goes through some .jpg images, sends those images to exiftool and outputs their exif information to a json file. I then bring the Json file into powershell using Get-Content and then I convert it to a PSObject using ConvertFrom-Json. I'm having trouble understanding how to access the data I need from the PSObject. For example I would like to get the FileName of the images and their exposure settings. I have tried psobject.properties.Name which only shows me the properties of the PSObject and not the actual objects within. I then tried Get-Member and some of its properties to no avail. I believe Get-Member is the route I need to go however I'm not entirely sure how to use it.

This is a very condensed example of the Json:

```
[
    "[{",
    "  \"FileName\": \"DJI_0001.JPG\",",
    "  \"ExposureTime\": 0.005,",
    "},",
    "{",
    "  \"FileName\": \"DJI_0002.JPG\",",
    "  \"ExposureTime\": 0.003125,",
    "},",
    "{",
    "  \"FileName\": \"DJI_0004.JPG\",",
    "  \"ExposureTime\": 0.00625,",
    "}]"
]
```

This is some code I have tried:

```
$scriptDir = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent

Write-Host "Procesing Files..."

$command = $scriptDir + '\exiftool.exe ' + $directory + ' -json -n -r -EXT JPG'

$allmetadata = Invoke-Expression $command

#Write-Host $allmetadata

$allmetadata | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "$scriptDir\JsonOut.json" 

#########################################################################################################
#
# This Gets the Json File and converts it to a PSObject 
#
#########################################################################################################

$convertedmeta = Get-Content "$scriptDir/JsonOut.json" -Raw -Encoding UTF8 | ConvertFrom-Json

Write-Host $convertedmeta

#########################################################################################################
#
# This is code where I was trying to explore the information within the PSObject trying to figure out 
# where the FileName and ExpsoureTime are kept so I can call the values
#
#########################################################################################################

Write-Host "Exploring JSON File"
#$jsonInfoExplore = $convertedmeta.PsObject.Properties.Value.PsObject.Properties.Name
#$jsonInfoExplore = $convertedmeta.psobject.properties.Name
#$jsonInfoExplore = $convertedmeta.psobject.properties.Value
$jsonInfoExplore = $convertedmeta | Get-Member 

Write-Host $jsonInfoExplore
```

As you can see where the code has been commented out, I have tried several different ways to get the information I'm looking for. I just don't fully understand how to call the data from the PSObject.

Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That json looks bizarre, like everything is escaped.  You'd have to converto-json *twice*.

```
cat file.json | convertfrom-json | convertfrom-json

FileName     ExposureTime
--------     ------------
DJI_0001.JPG        0.005
DJI_0002.JPG     0.003125
DJI_0004.JPG      0.00625
```

It should really look like this, an array of three objects:

```
[{
  "FileName": "DJI_0001.JPG",
  "ExposureTime": 0.005,
},
{
  "FileName": "DJI_0002.JPG",
  "ExposureTime": 0.003125,
},
{
  "FileName": "DJI_0004.JPG",
  "ExposureTime": 0.00625,
}]
```

Comment: While I'm not too familiar with PS, it looks to me that the code takes the output of exiftool, which is already in json due to the `-json` option, and converts it to json again?  Specifically the line `$allmetadata | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "$scriptDir\JsonOut.json"`

Comment: @StarGeek That would explain it.

Comment: I didn't even realize what I did with the Json. I also thought the Json looked weird. I even validated it with JsonLint. I changed $allmetadata to $allmetadata | Out-File "$scriptDir\JsonOut.json" -Encoding UTF-8  The json file looks better now, so I'm going to spend some time playing with it to see if I can get what I want.